# read file system error on docker load image from tar file

Tags: docker

the image tar file is working on my laptop where I saved the image using docker save,
I tried to pass the image using my FlashDrive to my PC but when I tried to load the image to my desktop I got an error on this command:

```
docker load -i C:\Downloads\app_image.tar
```

```
error processing tar file(exit status 1) write/bv8979s8shdfushdxcxjkk12h3asidu103/layer.tar: read-only file system
```

I tried to redownload the `app_image.tar` and run the command again but I got the following:

```
mkdir /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-import-118474620: read-only file system
```

what does it mean?

Comment: can you add the make and model for both the laptop and the PC you're using? Also, more specifically, how's your PC storage configured and what OS is it running?